# How to set jQuery Plugin option based on attribute of current element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am setting up tooltips using [qTip](http://www.craigsworks.com/projects/qtip). I am wondering how can I set an option based on a attribute of the current element?

```
$('*[data-tip]').qtip({ // enable qTip on all elements that has the attribute 'data-tip'
    content: this.attr('data-tip'); // I can't get this to work, is it possible?
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to have access to each element (as `this`), like this:

```
$('*[data-tip]').each(function() {
  $(this).qtip({
    content: $(this).attr('data-tip');
  });
});
```

*However*, `*[data-tip]` is a *very* expensive selector (and can just be `[data-tip]`), if you can narrow it down so it's not checking for the attribute on *every* DOM element it would be much faster.

Also, in jQuery 1.4.3+, you can replace [`$(this).attr('data-tip')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with [`$(this).data('tip')`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), which looks at the `data-` attributes (if the key isn't present in the data object).